# Jwt и retrofit - авторизация и обновление токена

Tags: retrofit, jwt

В интернете есть примеры типа таких [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450036/refreshing-oauth-token-using-retrofit-without-modifying-all-calls)

Но я ни как не могу разобраться что там к чему..

при авторизации получаю 
token и refresh_token. Токен живет 10 минут, а после этого его нужно обновить.

Как организовать автообновление токена при ответе 401? Используя Interceptor или Authenticator. Можете дать рабочий пример?